# Excel Solver - Prevent Identically Named Results

Tags: excel, solver

This may sound a bit odd and maybe I'm just missing the forest through the trees on this question, but is there a way to force the Excel Solver to return only one instance of a result? As a short example imagine that we have some results on the likability of various objects (colors, animals, and shapes). We want the solver to return the three most preferred objects from this list.

Red (400)
   Dog (120)
   Circle (100)
   Red (400)
   Cat (90)
   Square (75)
   Blue (90)
   Horse (60)
   Triangle (70)
   Green (80)
   Snake (30)
   Rectangle (40)
   Yellow (40)
   Rabbit (20)
   Pentagon (15)

The problem is, of course, simplified in this example. Basically, my issue arises in that I want one of each type, namely Red, Dog, and Circle but I keep getting Red, Red (again), and Dog because the total is higher. I want to define a way to prevent Solver from returning two values named the same. I just can't seem to figure it out and Google doesn't seem to produce any viable responses either.

Comment: Finding the three most preferred (one from each category) seems like a *sorting* problem rather than an *optimization* problem -- so I am not sure how the Solver is even relevant. In any event, if you have several cell corresponding to `Red` (or to a more expansive category such as color) -- introduce new binary decision variables which correspond to selecting that object and constrain the sum of them to be <= 1 so that at most one such object is selected. Your question is on the vague side so I can't say more, but the solution probably involves constraints on the sums of binary variables.

Comment: It's unclear if you have structure in your data - e.g. is Red-Dog-Circle a record (row), or just Red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how your data is setup, and this could affect how you setup the Solver problem, but here is one method (nb - this method will only work if you have 200 or fewer values to choose from).

1. Make Column A for "Category". This would have values such as "Color", "Animal", and "Shape".
2. Column B would be for "Type", and contain the information you provided. (e.g. Dog, Cat, ... Red, Blue, ... Circle, Square, ...)
3. Column C is the Value or Score for the type shown in Column B, again the information you provided.
4. Column D has fields that Solver will manipulate, let's call it "Selected". Selected will be a 0 or a 1.
5. Column E is the result of selection, a simple calculation, `=C2*D2`, filled down.
6. Make Cell H2 the sum of Column E. This will be your objective for Solver.
7. Make G3 through G5 the values in "Category" (Color, Animal, Shape).
8. Make H3 through H5 the total selected values in each category. That is `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$16,"="&G3,$D$2:$D$16)` filled down.

The workbook looks like this ...

[image]

... from this, you can setup Solver with the following ...

1. Set Objective: is `$H$2`
2. To: is set to Max. (i.e. you are looking for the most preferred)
3. By Changing Variable Cells: is set to `$D$2:$D$16`
4. Subject to the Constraints: has four entries. `$D$2:$D$16 = binary`; `$H$3 = 1`; `$H$4 = 1`; `$H$5 = 1`
5. Select a Solving Method: is set to Evolutionary. You can use GRG Nonlinear, but it takes longer.

The dialog looks like this ...

[image]

... with the following result, which meets your criteria ...

[image]

Comment: Your answer gets me so very close, and thank you for that! My data is formatted almost exactly as you have it also so that pleases me too. One small wrinkle that perhaps wasn't made clear in the original post, what if a "Type" is used more than once across two "Categories" but I only want one "Type" as a response? Think of it like this, Orange can be a "Color" (Value 150) and (While not shown in the original example) could be a "Fruit" category (Value 130). However, I only want the color answer, not the fruit one.

Comment: Another example would be this; say a person works well in two departments and is graded out as the top resource in each department. However, we can only assemble a leadership team where all departments are represented equally if an individual represents only a single department on that team. Despite being the top resource for each department, how do we force Solver to take the second best resource from one of the departments? In this example Department = Category and Name = Type.

Comment: You can create a constraint using the SUMIF function against whatever column you choose.

Comment: So you're saying use SUMIF on the Type or Name column? Am I following you correctly?

Comment: Yes. Define "Orange" as something you want to constrain and put a constraint for "<= 1".

Comment: just doesn't seem to work for me honestly...I'm sure you're right but I'd have to set a constraint for every option and Solver has a limit of 100 constraints which makes it impossible given my data set. I tried too because it made logical sense what you were saying, unfortunately the 100 constraint limit prevented me. I have 196 employees over seven departments. That already puts me way over the constraint limit.

Comment: In that case, a User Defined Function (UDF) could be written that determines the maximum number of times any "type" or "name" is selected.